# How to handle content of dynamically multiple fragments from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a simple exam questions app. that's why I have created dynamically multiple fragments as per questions.
the fragment contains TextView for a question and 4 RadioButtons for options. There is one Button in activity to clear selection(if the answer selected).
I have created *interface* for that and implement the method into a fragment and try to uncheck all the radio buttons but the method is calling but radio buttons are most of the time still checked and few times uncheck. I didn't get exactly what happing please help.

When I recheck all things I found one thing when I select 8 options of 8 questions in a row and start to uncheck each from the first fragment. when I was at the 0th position of the fragment and click on the button it unchecks the checkbox but when I scroll to the next fragment(1st) and click on the button and it unchecks the 2nd positions fragment respectively 2nd unchecks 3rd, 3rd unchecks 4th, 4th unchecks 5th, 5th nothing happen, 6th unchecks 7th. please tell me how can I solve this issue.

Code as bellow,

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        public int getCount() {
            return titles.size();
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            QuestionsFragment fragment = new QuestionsFragment();
            fragment.setText(titles.get(position), position); //

            return fragment;
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
            QuestionsFragment fragment = (QuestionsFragment)item;
            String title = fragment.getText();
            int position = titles.indexOf(title);
            if (position >= 0) {
                return position;
            } else {
                return POSITION_NONE;
            }
        }
    });
```

Interface:

```
public interface ClearSelection {
public void reamoveAllSelections();}
```

Fragment:

```
public final class QuestionsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_fragment, null);

    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
    rbOptionOne = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_option_one);
    rbOptionTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_option_two);
    rbOptionThree = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_option_three);
    rbOptionFour = view.findViewById(R.id.rb_option_four);

((QuestionsActivity)getActivity()).clearSelectionApi(new ClearSelection() {
        @Override
        public void reamoveAllSelections() {
            if (rbOptionOne.isChecked()) {
                rbOptionOne.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (rbOptionTwo.isChecked()) {
                rbOptionTwo.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (rbOptionThree.isChecked()) {
                rbOptionThree.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (rbOptionFour.isChecked()) {
                rbOptionFour.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

return view;
}}
```

Or please suggest me if any alternate option to do the same thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try use this code in OnAttach() fragment method.